# admin.addpeers is not working on geth

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, dapps, geth-debugging, private

This is the info i get when i run `admin.addpeer` on geth . i have used same genesis file on both aws instances, also rpcport and ports are different on both instances. the info is as follows:

```
WARN [12-22|04:25:39.259] Served parity_netPeers                   conn=193.56.29.33:35476   reqid=3 t="16.68µs"   err="the method parity_netPeers does not exist/is not available"
WARN [12-22|04:25:39.259] Served admin_peers                       conn=193.56.29.33:35474   reqid=3 t="27.114µs"  err="the method admin_peers does not exist/is not available"
INFO [12-22|04:25:39.870] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=125 static=0
WARN [12-22|04:25:42.307] Served eth_signTransaction               conn=217.12.208.7:52372   reqid=1 t="103.282µs" err="tx fee (23.40 ether) exceeds the configured cap (1.00 ether)"
ERROR[12-22|04:25:45.074] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=f25a8758 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
WARN [12-22|04:25:48.502] Served eth_signTransaction               conn=217.12.208.7:52372   reqid=1 t="96.657µs"  err="tx fee (23.40 ether) exceeds the configured cap (1.00 ether)"
INFO [12-22|04:25:49.889] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=112 static=0
WARN [12-22|04:25:52.176] Served admin_peers                       conn=217.12.203.122:49260 reqid=1 t="29.063µs"  err="the method admin_peers does not exist/is not available"
WARN [12-22|04:25:53.034] Served parity_netPeers                   conn=217.12.203.122:49260 reqid=1 t="19.609µs"  err="the method parity_netPeers does not exist/is not available"
```

pls help, struggling for so many days. Geth version is : 1.10.8-stable

Comment: How do you run geth node? show cmd line and why is your log talking about method of Parity?